# Android advertisement

Tags: android, ads

I am starting to develop an Android app and I have seen that in other apps are things like: download this free game and you will earn 10 coins for you.

I suppose that there some company that gives that service (am I right?) and the app developers get paid for this action.

Does anybody know a company that gives this service, I mean I put some apps to download and I get paid for each download.

How is this type of advertisement called?
 Any companies that give this service? Thanks

update:
I think I have expressed want I wanted wrong. I know about advertisement companies and how to add their code. Just want to know about a company that show offers to the client. The client completes an offer and I get paid. Then I give something for the game to the client. Just like in app payment but the client doesn't have to spend money.

Comment: it speaks about advertising, but not he type of advertising i wanted... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must take a look at this

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

You can find here how to insert ads in your app with some very usefull tutorials.

Comment: i think i have expressed want i wanted wrong. I know about advertisment compnayes and how to add their code. Just want to knwo a bout a company that show offers to the client. The client completes an offer and i get paid. Then i give someting for the game to de client. Just like in app payment but the client doesnt have to spend money.

Comment: Ok, this web is in Spanish...AndroidApps.es
In google ads you can register as advertiser, take a look inside admob.com...and look for it

Comment: Take a look here https://accounts.google.com/Login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fadwords.google.com%2Fum%2Fgaiaauth%3Fapt%3DNone%26ltmpl%3Dadwords%26ltmpl%3Dadwords&service=adwords&ifr=false&dsh=-8092079654464339499&ltmpl=adwords&alwf=true&ltmpl=adwords&sarp=1&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

There are mobile advertisement companies (InMobi, Google, MoPub etc...) that help you in this direction.

What I believe your question is : "Let's say you have a game and after user completes level 1 he will get an Ad saying install some xyz app and unlock next level - If user install xyz app you get money for that and user gets next level unlocked"

### Few things

Ad network serves you Ad

Ad gets rendered

When user clicks ad a click is recorded in some click tracking server

When user opens xyz app that user installed via ad another response is recorded in server

I think the app logic should handle to check whether both click and response of xyz app open is present in order to allow user to go next level